# Select duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a set of duplicate records in a SQL db like so:

```
Id  |   Prop1  |   Prop2
--------------------------
1   |   aaa    |   aaa
2   |   aaa    |   aaa
3   |   bbb    |   bbb
4   |   bbb    |   bbb
5   |   ccc    |   ccc
6   |   ccc    |   ccc
```

I need to select each duplicate, or every second row to update it. Would like to get a select statement returning ids

```
2, 4, 6
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. :) What have you tried?

Comment: You want result in 1 row?

Comment: Select duplicates and select every second row are two different things, what do you actually want? What if there are more than two?

Comment: What to do if 3 or more equal prop1/prop2 rows?

Comment: Yes, I should mention I will always have two records per item. Hence #jpw answer is a perfect solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select max(id) id
from table 
group by Prop1, Prop2
having count(*) > 1
```

This would return the highest id for each duplicate group which with your sample data would be 2,4,6. This might, or might not be what you want - the question is a bit ambiguous.

Note that this might not be the correct solution if there can be more than one duplicate row.

Comment: @lad2025 I know, which is why I wrote _This would return the highest id for each duplicate group_ If there can be more duplicates then the row_number solution is what the OP should use (and maybe even if there's just one dupe). The sample data and wording of the question (_every second row_) suggested that might not be the case though.

Comment: This suits my needs perfectly, since I will always have two records per item

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca4423/1/0)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
       Id
      ,[rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Prop1, Prop2 ORDER BY Id)
   FROM your_tab
)
SELECT Id
FROM cte
WHERE [rn] <> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in following:

```
select * 
from (select *, 
             row_number() over (partition by Prop1, Prop2 order by id) rn
      from tbl
      )x
where rn <> 1 -- at this part you will get all duplicates (even if more than 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT max(y.id), x.Prop1, x.Prop2 
FROM YourTab y,
  ( SELECT Prop1, Prop2 FROM YourTab
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    GROUP BY Prop1,Prop2 ) x
WHERE y.Prop1 = x.Prop1 AND y.Prop2 = y.Prop2
GROUP BY x.Prop1, x.Prop2
```

Comment: Instead of where you can maybe use a inner join clause ... for instance in Postgresql it should work